# Ending "let me know xxx" with a question mark or period?

Tags: punctuation, question-marks, periods

I am writing an email. The last line of the email is as follows:

> Let me know when can I come for the same?

I am asking a question but at the same time I am starting the sentence with let me know. In such a scenario, should I end my statement with a question mark or a period?

Comment: This is common enough in casual usage—I routinely do things like this in email and chat—but for formal usage, it would not be a good idea. For one thing, it would be more common to un-invert the syntax: "Let me know *when I can come*...". I'm not sure whether there's a regional usage, since I think I've heard the syntax you describe often from Indian coworkers, but the most formal usage would recast the sentence as a simple imperative sentence. Mind you, I personally wouldn't say that email *needs* to follow the most formal usage.

Comment: Even interrogative sentences used to convey polite requests often have no question mark nowadays. "Could you shut the window, please, John." Some even allow the practice for rhetorical questions.

Comment: That's ungrammatical in English.

Comment: That is ungrammatical in English because the word order is wrong: subject–verb inversion is mandatory in the subordinate clause uses for this circumstance.

Comment: Or this? [Punctuation for a 'non-question question'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125897/punctuation-for-a-non-question-question/125905#125905)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not asking a question.  You are making a statement that someone should notify you.  Your statement is similar to a question in that it expresses your need to know when you can *come for the same*.  You also have your subject and verb transposed.

> Let me know when I can come for the same.

is in some ways no different from

> Take the dog for a walk.

The first tells your audience to do something - share information with you.  The second tells your audience to do something - walk the dog.

A question is interrogative.  It requests an answer.  *Let me know when I can come for the same,* does not request an answer.  Your audience may often respond to statements by saying, *OK*, which merely acknowledges they hear you but has nothing to do with *when you can come for the same*.  People may also respond to statements by saying, *No*.  That, however, does not make your statement a question.  It merely means your audience heard your demand and is letting you know they will not being doing what you expect.

Your statement as a question is -

> When can I come for the same?

Now your audience has been prompted to provide that answer.  If you know, however, that your audience does not currently know when *you can come for the same*, asking, *When can I come for the same,* is pointless and confusing.

So what you are saying in your statement is that you suspect your audience does not know when you can come but when they do determine when you can come, they should let you know.  It can be thought of as asking a question today with the expectation of an answer in the future.  Even though your statement is NOT a question and should not contain a question mark, it will be understood as a question.

Comment: Not all statements that end with a question mark need to be questions, and it's common to use a question mark as a shorthand for *will you?*, etc. *Maybe try to address that in your answer?*

Answer (score 2):

In formal writing, requests do not require a question mark. Please only use a period.

If you were texting a friend or writing a comic book, the question mark could imply that you are using a inquisitive tone and requesting a response.
In formal writing, you are stating something. You are (not harshly) demanding an action be taken or directing someone(s).

"Please let me know if I can be of any additional assistance."

If you wanted to ask for a response, it should be something more like:

"Will you please let me know if I can assist you further?" Or - more succinctly: "Can I help you with anything else?" Or - in your very specific case: "Will you please let me know when I can come for the same?"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with EllieK that your statement is not a question - it's an imperative statement, with *let me know...* formulating a request - and that it should be written without inversion:

> Let me know when I can come for the same.

I do not think placing a question mark at the end of it is necessarily *wrong*. There are cases in English when a question mark can be placed at the end of a sentence that is not a question - for example, to express doubt or disbelief:

> He won a million dollars. *("basic" statement - I know that he won and I believe it)*
>
> Did he win a million dollars? *("basic" yes/no question - I don't know whether he won and want to learn)*
>
> He won a million dollars? *(expression of doubt - I've learned that he won, but I want to confirm it/don't believe it)*

For declarative sentences, this is called a [rising declarative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rising_declarative) (due to the rising intonation at the end of such a sentence in speech, represented in writing by a question mark).

In your case, you place a question mark at the end of an imperative sentence. There's much less information on rising imperatives - [the paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/230177521.pdf) I've found goes into a bit of academic detail - but it's not an uncommon pattern either.

Typically, using a rising intonation (and a question mark in writing) at the end of an imperative sentence serves to soften it and make it appear as more of a suggestion than as an instruction. To take the example from the paper:

> A: I really like this present grandma gave me.
>
> a. B: Write her a thank-you note. *(more definite, imposing the idea - you should write the note)*
>
> b. B: Write her a thank-you note? *(more suggestive, just sharing the idea - maybe you could write the note)*

In your case, the question mark makes the suggestion more polite (perhaps overly polite) - you're not *requesting* that the other person lets you know, you're merely *suggesting* that they do so, and indicating that they shouldn't feel an obligation to let you know.

Comment: Good point. Now I understand what you were saying, Maciej. I considered that the example statement could include a question mark and be presented as a question but using rising intonation at the end of the statement does not ask *When can I come*, it instead asks, *Will you tell me*. The answer to that question is yes or no, not a date and time. I would only ask, *Will you tell me [when I can come]*, if I thought there could be a reason that my audience might not tell me. In my experience, *Let me know **when***, is almost never asked.  *Let me know **if***, is more likely to be asked.

Comment: @EllieK I think what's confusing is that there's multiple levels of indirection - the first level is turning a wh-question into a request (*When can I come?* -> *Let me know when I can come*), and the second level is making that request a rising imperative with a question mark (*Let me know...* -> *Let me know...?*). But that second change does not actually make it a yes/no question in my opinion - it's closer to constructions such as *Do X, will you?* in that they do not demand an answer.