# Ending "let me know xxx" with a question mark or period?

Tags: punctuation

I am writing an email. The last line of the email is as follows -

> Let me know when can I come for the same?

I am asking a question but at the same time I am starting the sentence with let me know. In such a scenario, should I end my statement with a question mark or a period?

PS: The question seemed more suited for ell.stackexchange community. So, I asked the same question there - https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/302809/ending-let-me-know-xxx-with-a-question-mark-or-period/302851#302851.